# Python module: Limit importable functions in a module

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

Given there is a python module below

```py
__all__ = ["some_func"]

def some_func():
    pass

def internal_use_only():
    # some dangerous operations
```

In such case, how can I prevent user calling the function `internal_use_only()` that's something I don't want user to call by accident. Even if I use `__all__` name scope, I can only limit wild card import but user can call it by

```py
import above_module

above_module.internal_use_only()
```

Would it be possible to limit accessing specific function/class by importing?

Comment: The commonly-understood convention is to use a leading underscore on the name `_internal_use_only`.  This will also mean you don't really need to use `__all__`, since underscore names are not exported by default.

Comment: Depending on how your module itself uses `internal_use_only`, you can add `del internal_use_only` to the end of the module. This only works if the function exists to be called while the module is being defined, not if the name is used as a global variable in another function defined by the module.

Comment: if `internal_use_only()` is only called by say `some_func()` it is possible to define it inside `some_func()` making it mostly invisible (outside of `some_func()`)